# What does OA3x mean in WMIC Command oa3xoriginalproductkey

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-activation, product-key, wmic

I am asking out of curiosity to know. What does `OA3x` mean in `WMIC PATH SOFTWARELICENSINGSERVICE GET OA3xOriginalproductkey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OA 3.0 is the product activation standard for Microsoft.
This program enables OEMs to digitally order and receive product keys
from, and report computer information to, Microsoft as well as enable
activation of software on specific hardware.

Reference :
[Microsoft OEM Activation (OA) & MDOS Onboarding Training](https://mdossea.blob.core.windows.net/onboarding/OEM%20Onboarding%20Training%20(October%202019).pptx?sp=r&st=2021-08-16T11:50:50Z&se=2025-08-16T19:50:50Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=b&sig=nuBZBzaJDkYLefzmjoiVfLseDXr%2BmtiBpMDSg8m8DQU%3D).

OA seems to be the Microsoft protocol for OEM Activation
(**O**EM **A**ctivation).
It seems to be called `OA3x` as a possible reference to a future
protocol version of OA 3.x.